# How to creat a pivot-table with multiple line fields using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I want to create a pivot table with multiple line fields. Although, these line fields need to be changed accordingly to data in typed in excel sheet.

I have tried setting the variables and using "with" and "for" commands, such as in the following code.

```
    Option Explicit 
Private Sub PivotTable()

        Dim Wsheet      As Worksheet, Wsheet2   As Worksheet
        Dim File        As Workbook
        Dim PvtCache    As PivotCache
        Dim Pvtbl       As PivotTable
        Dim RLast       As Double
        Dim i           As Variant, X            As Variant

        Set File = ThisWorkbook
        Set Wsheet = Sheets("Data")
        'Create sheet for pivot table 
        Set Wsheet2 = Sheets.Add(After:=Wsheet)
        Wsheet2.Name = "PivotTable"     

        Set PvtCache = File.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatWsheetse, SourceData:=Wsheet.Range("A1:D45"))
        Set Pvtbl = Wsheet2.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=Wsheet2.Range("A3"), TableName:="Manual_Bordo")

            With Pvtbl
            'setting rows fields
            Set Wsheet = Sheets("Data")
            RLast = Wsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 'Type the row fields in column "F".
            For i = 1 To RLast
                Set X = Wsheet.Range("F" & i)
                With .PivotFields(X)                            'Here i get  the error 1004
                    .Orientation = xlRowField
                    .Position = i
                End With

            Next
            'setting pivot Data
                With .PivotFields("Size")
                    .Orientation = xlDataField
                    .Position = i
                    .Function = xlSum
                    .NumberFormat = "#.##0,0"
                    .Name = "Size"
                End With
            Next            
        End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

But instead working I get the error 1004: cannot get the pivotfields property of the pivot table class (Sorry if it doesn't make sense, but I had to translate the dialog box).

Comment: Pivot tables via VBA can be difficult. Suggest try recording a macro while setting it up manually, then cleaning up the recorded macro.

Comment: Do you expect `X`  to be a number? Like ` With .PivotFields(10)`?  If so, change `X` from `Variant` to `Long` and just do `X = Wsheet.Range("F" & i).Value`...if that's what you mean?

Comment: @BruceWayne I expect that X would be a row label as in `.PivotFields("DATA")`. It would be easier to create my pivot tables. Even though, I'll try your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: @Rildo - Oh! First, I'd rename `X` so it's more clear -- but try this instead `Dim rowLabel as String // ... // rowLabel = Wsheet.Range("F" & i)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you for the idea. I use a much bigger database with over 30 columns, though. Therefore, I need to create different pivot tables just by selecting the row field instead of hard code.

Comment: Once you do one, you can just alter the code to provide for that.  Then you only need to concentrate on a small area of the code.

Comment: When you set the data field you're still using `i` - shouldn't that be `1` ?

Comment: @BruceWayne, It worked very well.

Comment: @Rildo - Did that solve the issue?

Comment: @TimWilliams, you are right. thank you for pointing that out. Since I have headers in column "F", I just changed `.Position = i -1`.

Comment: @BruceWayne, YES. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an object where you just need a string. (I'm also renaming `X` to make it more clear):

```
Dim rowLabel as String
...
rowLabel = Wsheet.Range("F" & i)
With .PivotFields(rowLabel)
    ...
```